# Can levels of nesting in conjunctions be unambiguously systematically parsed?

Tags: computational-linguistics, conjunctions, recursion

[This question on NLP](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/how-to-parse-conjunctions-in-natural-language-processing-in-python/7883#7883) asks for the how of parsing, and the given answer shows how the state-of-the-art isn't at that level. But whether this is a *hard* problem or not is not *my* question: what I ask is, is it a *possibility* to unambiguously parse sentences for levels of nesting?

Comment: That seems to depend on what kind of input you use. Written sentences are almost impossible to parse unambiguously, as [this paper](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/abney95c.pdf) pointed out long ago. Humans using real (spoken) language are much better because they're not limited to written input without intonation, rhythm, gaze direction, gestures, etc, and we use them all. Writing is neolithic technology. English writing is paleolithic.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Do you require the parsings to be correct?  If so, of course you need to know how human speakers of the language actually do parse them.  A beginning can be made by examining anaphoric relationships among the members of 3 or more coordinated items, which McCawley does in *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.